# Woocommerce api - create customer - email notification

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the woocommerce api with https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library.

I have enabled customer registration email notification in Woocommerce settings -> Email.

I would like to know whether the customer receive the email if the customer is created through the api.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a Customer is created via the API, they receive the same email notification that would be sent if they had created their account through the website.